# Why does the first call to DecryptUpdate in AES-CBC return 16 fewer bytes?

Tags: encryption

While decrypting a file by CBC mode of AES algorithm, the output length is 16 bytes lesser than that of the input length. For example if you pass a buffer of 512 bytes it decrypts 496 bytes. It happens only in CBC mode for the first call of `EVP_DecryptUpdate()`. Why is it so?

```
while((bytes = fread (buffer, 1, 32, fp)) != 0) 
{
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(e, buffer_out, &c_len, buffer, bytes);
    ret = fwrite(buffer_out, 1, c_len, fpout); 
    printf("c_len %d bytes %d ret %d\n", c_len, bytes, ret);
}
```

Comment: But padding is for last data chunk isn't it? Why should it matter for the beginning of a file?

Comment: @Rak Explainted that in my answer...forgot to add it initially, I've slanted the text. CTR directly encrypts/decrypts bits and doesn't have this issue, but it is (even) more vulnerable to IV reuse - you *need* to prefix ciphertext with the IV (or derive the IV some other way).

Answer (score 11):

AES operates over blocks of 16 bytes.  The `EVP_DecryptUpdate()` will operate on blocks of 16.  As long as you are using `EVP_DecryptUpdate()` it assumes that you will give it more data to decrypt, and retains the last block of data within the crypt context.  This is because in CBC mode it needs the next cipher block to be the IV for the next block of decryption because it can't predict when it will need it to calculate  the padding.

[Wiki Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CBC)

[image]

The "decrypted length" will be exactly one block (16 bytes) less than what you give it for the first iteration because it retains the 2nd block of data.  Once you decrypt the 2nd iteration it outputs block 2 and block 3 (32 bytes), and retains block 4.  Extrapolating this out to the end of your encrypted file you'll realize that you would be 1 block short.  Once you call `EVP_DecryptFinal` the final block is decrypted (padding taken care of if necessary), and output to the buffer given for the full 32 blocks (512 bytes in your example).

[Example Code](https://kahdev.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/decrypting-with-the-openssl-api/)

```
char *decrypt (char *key,
               char *iv,
               char *encryptedData,
               int encryptedLength)
{
    // Initialisation
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *cryptCtx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(cryptCtx);
    int decryptedLength = 0;
    int allocateSize = encryptedLength * sizeof(char);
    int lastDecryptLength = 0;
    char *decryptedData = (char *) malloc (allocateSize);
    memset(decryptedData, 0x00, allocateSize);
    int decryptResult = EVP_DecryptInit_ex(cryptCtx,
        EVP_bf_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);

    // EVP_DecryptInit_ex returns 1 if it succeeded.
    if (decryptResult == 1)
    {
        decryptResult = EVP_DecryptUpdate(cryptCtx, decryptedData,
            &decryptedLength, encryptedData, encryptedLength);

        // Note that EVP_DecryptUpdate will alter the value of the third parameter 
        // to be equal to the amount of data that was written. This is not always the    
        // entire length of the decrypted data! To finish the decryption process, use 
        // EVP_DecryptFinal_ex. This will decrypt any remaining data.

        // Cleanup
        if (decryptResult == 1)
        {
            // Stick the final data at the end of the last
            // decrypted data.
            EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(cryptCtx,
                decryptedData + decryptedLength,
                &lastDecryptLength);
            decryptedLength = decryptedLength + lastDecryptLength;
            decryptedData[decryptedLength – 1] = ”;
            printf ("Decrypted size: %d\n", decryptedLength);
            printf ("Decrypted data: \n%s\n\n", decryptedData);
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("EVP_DeccryptUpdate failure.\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("EVP_DecryptInit_ex failure.\n");
    }
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(cryptCtx);
    EVP_cleanup();
    return decryptedData;
}
```

Comment: Actually encryption and decryption are happening fine. I am using the final_ex functions for both encryption and decryption. I also saw the comment in your program saying that decrypteLength may not be the actual length. But why? Why is it happening only for first chunk(or the first call of decryption) ?

Comment: Can you post your code?  I'm confused as to what your problem is if encryption and decryption are happening fine.

Comment: To confirm the reason behind the 16 byte lesser decryptLength for the first block in decryption. Even if it is being used as IV why the length should be lesser?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the first block of data.  If you could post the relevant portions of your code it would help to understand the issue you're having.

Comment: while((bytes = fread (buffer, 1, 32, fp)) != 0)  
  {    
 EVP_DecryptUpdate(e, buffer_out, &c_len, buffer, bytes);    
 ret = fwrite(buffer_out, 1, c_len, fpout);  
 printf("c_len %d bytes %d ret %d\n", c_len, bytes, ret);  
  }  

For the first read of the encrypted file c_len[decrypted len] is 16 though I send 32 bytes for decryption. For latter iterations it is 32. I just want know the reason behind that lesser 16 bytes.

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting. I am not able to do it.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @Rak You cannot decrypt the first block of ciphertext unless you've previously given it the IV. If you don't supply an IV, it's likely assuming your first block of ciphertext is the IV. IVs are **not** ciphertext, and are **not** decrypted, so if it's treating your first block of ciphertext as an IV it's not treating it as ciphertext.

Comment: Thank you dude. This is not observed in other modes like CTR, CFB or OFB because in those modes either plain or ciphertexts are directly XORed with the pseudo random bytes and those data are not required for the next operation.

Comment: This is not right. The ciphertext can be put/kept in memory *and* be used as vector for the next block encrypt/decrypt just fine. The full blocks need to be available, but once the blocks are available they can be decrypted.

Answer (score 3):

CBC is a block *mode of operation*. One way to look at modes of operation to see the block cipher as a configuration parameter for the mode of operation. Each block cipher has a specific block size. This matters as modes of operation such as CBC require plaintext *blocks* as input. For AES the block size is always 128 bits / 16 bytes, regardless of the key size.

One problem with ECB and CBC is that they requires blocks of input. However, not all plaintext consist of a full number of blocks; the last part of the plaintext may only contain a partial block of binary data. Usually this problem is solved by padding the plaintext using a padding scheme. The PKCS#7 padding scheme is the most prominent padding scheme at the moment. Other solutions are possible, such as different padding modes or ciphertext stealing.

PKCS#7 padding is always applied, even if the the last block of plaintext is fully present. This allows the user to put in *any* binary message. If PKCS#7 padding wasn't always applied then messages might end with trailing bytes that might be interpreted as padding. Other padding modes such as zero padding (just padding with `00` bytes up to the end of the block) means that messages cannot end with `00` value as they might be stripped off during unpadding.

*The problem is that an implementation of CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding doesn't know when the end of the ciphertext is reached when it is fed partial ciphertext. This means that it cannot directly decrypt and return the bytes it receives: it may be that those bytes contain padding of the plaintext message rather than the message itself. Hence it will buffer at least the last (partial block) until `EVP_DecryptFinal(_ex)` method is called.*

Most other modes of operation turn the block cipher into a stream cipher (except the insecure ECB mode of operation). So you would not have this particular issue if you were using CTR, CFB or OFB modes of operation. Stream ciphers encrypt each bit - practically speaking each byte - of plaintext separately even if the underlying cipher has a larger block size. The fact that you can encrypt / decrypt each byte directly is called the *online* property of a cipher.

Comment: The OP is asking why during decryption the first iteration of decrypting 32 bytes yields 16 bytes of decrypted data (returned in the length variable).  Not 16 bytes more.

Comment: @raz And it does: "A full block of padding was added [during encryption] and removed during decryption."

Answer (score 0):

EVP has padding turned **on** by default.

After you initialize `EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, ...)`, call `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0)`. Do this for both - encrypt & decrypt `ctx`!